# Why do MOSFETs keep blowing after I replace them in a kickscooter controller?

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, induction-motor, repair

I have a few Segway Ninebot ES4 kickscooter controllers that I would like to learn how to fix.

Essentially at some point the motor ceased and seems to be fused, won't accelerate, won't brake, and even if power is off there is resistance in the motor rotation.

I narrowed it down to a blown MOSFET related to one of the motor leads. The MOSFET beeped with the continuity test so I concluded it was blown. I tried replacing the MOSFET, at first with one that had the same model number as the originals and after that blew as well I upgraded to a slightly more powerful MOSFET that blew as well.

The MOSFETs blow pretty much immediately after trying to ride the scooter. At first when I put everything back together, the motor spins freely, then when I try to ride it, immediately the motor starts vibrating and eventually dies in like 3 meters of riding. I can accelerate without load and seems to be fixed, but right after adding load, the motor starts vibrating and the MOSFET blows.

This is where I am stuck now, the same MOSFET keeps blowing. What is causing it to blow? Is it the MOSFET driver?

Has anyone here on this forum repaired Ninebot ES4 (or similar) motor controllers with the same issue? What can I try? I have two boards like this that I would like to learn how to fix this kind of issue with.

Info:
Original MOSFETs on the board: NCEP01T13A (Tried replacing with same model from another dead controller)
Secondly tried replacing with: IRF3808 (It was the closest match I could find that was sold in my country)

Pictures were to large to add directly but I did not want to lose quality so I put them on Google Drive for some time:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NZizmvtqdIiOTcaqg5oKKYEOSOMuvynv?usp=sharing

Comment: MOSFETs usually get damaged when they're overloaded, the current or voltage is too high. In your case chances are that the current becomes too high. It is unlikely that the MOSFET driver is at fault, if the driver is faulty, replacing the MOSFETs would not make things work again for a short time. My guess is that you should forget about the MOSFETs for a moment and look at the motor. The motor should not draw more current than the MOSFETs can handle. What is also possible is that there is an overcurrent detection that is broken. Include a schematic to see if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will test different motors. Unfortunately I have not yet found a schematic for the boards, what I found: there are 4 types made in these scooters with slight variations, I have 2 of the 4 types with blown Mosfets. One looks like this (pic from google): https://content.invisioncic.com/r254450/monthly_2019_01/UNADJUSTEDNONRAW_thumb_7435.jpg.acc2bd248bb3f9945f1a184dff5a110e.jpg
I don't have my boards with me currently. If there is an overcurrent detection (there probably is with these controllers), what components on the board would it include? What can I test and swap?

Comment: When you say you can accelerate with no load, do you mean that the wheels are off the floor?  If it is working in this state, you could use an oscilloscope to look at the gate on each mosfet to see if they have a valid pwm signal.

Comment: Yes, I mean off the floor. I would have to find an oscilloscope, that would take time but I will keep that in mind, thanks. Is a simple multimeter too slow to understand / measure a pwm signal? (I think it probably is.)

Comment: They can also be destroyed from too much *power* dissipated. High current and high voltage are both fine as long as the other one is low. But medium current and medium voltage at the same time can also blow the MOSFET. And this *could* be caused by a MOSFET driver. @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: It could also be another component near the MOSFET such as a diode, which is not protecting the MOSFET from voltage spikes.

Comment: Update: Swapped out the broken MOSFET again and tried another motor, issue still exists. I could ride for like 10 meters and from the start the vibration in the motor got worse and then eventually died - So the motor is not at fault with this. Next I would have to figure out how the overcurrent detection works and if it is broken. Any ideas what would the overcurrent protection look like? What components to check? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: I added pictures of my own board as a link to the original post. @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Mosfets designed for switching should always have the gate be driven fully on or fully off.  If they are half-on, they may pass enough current to run the motor with no load, but run it under load and the mosfet will rapidly overheat.  Check what is driving the gate of the mosfet to ensure it's not giving a vague half-on voltage.

Comment: Tested the Gate voltage on both a working MOSFET lines with a and the one in question with a multimeter. Both got a voltage of 5.9V. Sadly I don't have a working controller currently to test if ~6V is the correct gate voltage for Ninebot motor MOSFETS. The MOSFETS are rated 10V and I assume that no one really goes up to the max voltage or is it supposed to go to 10V to be fully open? @SimonB

Comment: I continued testing and learned this: On a working motor phase MOSFET the Drain Voltage (Source was "-" or ground or 0 right?) is 50V (battery is 36V, 5200mAh, so there is some voltage step up going on here). Now on the motor phase FET that keeps burning up the Drain voltage is 24V (Gate is 5.9V as others), so it appears that something else is eating up the rest of the volts. While running without load it runs (vibrates a bit but lasts way longer) but the FET keeps building up heat very quick and I assume eventually it will burn it. Other FETs don't heat up the same way.Where can the issue be?

Answer (score 2):

I see for D1X resistor can be seen darker/damaged, check it. See too for ceramic capacitor near mosfet and reisitor D1C bellow for cold solder and check/replace pulse diode. It is worth measuring or preferably replacing the current resistor R002 on the right side of the mosfet.